# Execute left join query in JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I have two tables, one for party and one for scorecard template mapping. The scorecard template mapping table has a foreign key back to the party (on id). I want to find a list of all of the parties that have scorecard template mapping details.

But I get an error which says :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   on near line 1, column 172 [select new
>   ScorecardTemplateMapping(p,temMap.scoTemplate,temMap.wrkFlwTemplate)
>   from com.kpisoft.common.web.domain.Party p left outer join
>   ScorecardTemplateMapping temMap on  temMap.organization.id=p.id and
>   temMap.gradeType.id=:gradeType  where
>   p.organization.organizationTypeId=:orgType and p.clientId=:clientId
>   order by p.organization.name]

This is my query:

> Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select new
>   ScorecardTemplateMapping(p,temMap.scoTemplate,temMap.wrkFlwTemplate)
>   from Party p left outer join ScorecardTemplateMapping temMap on 
>   temMap.organization.id=p.id and temMap.gradeType.id=:gradeType  where
>   p.organization.organizationTypeId=:orgType and p.clientId=:clientId
>   order by p.organization.name");

I have no idea why this isn't working. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Error message about syntax error is quite clear:

```
unexpected token: on
```

There is no support to make join with ON [conditional] in JPQL (ON is not reserved word). How joins are made in JPQL, is told for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28613_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_Joins). It boils down to that you have to present join condition in where clause.